# A multi native window using flex which open in one Adobe AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

i'm new in flash builder. 
i would like to know if there any solution to create a multi native window using flex which open in one Adobe AIR application? and there are given a choice to select how many native window to open. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    import mx.core.Window;

    private function btn_click():void 
    {
        var opts:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
        opts.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL; //NativeWindowType.NORMAL, NativeWindowType.UTILITY



        var nativewin:NativeWindow;
        for(var num:int = 0; num< comboBox.selectedItem; num++)
        {

        nativewin = new NativeWindow(opts);
        nativewin.width = 320;
        nativewin.height = 200;
        nativewin.activate();
    }

    }   


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
    <mx:Label text="buttonAlignment:"/>
    <mx:ComboBox id="comboBox"
                 dataProvider="[1,2,3,4]" />
</mx:ApplicationControlBar>

<mx:Button label="Launch {comboBox.selectedItem} window"
           click="btn_click();" />
```